# best way to query the nodes in a variable path length in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking at a variable path length of our customer interactions after install. I would like to know how many paths contain 1,2,3 and so on 'Calls to Care' events. I have written this query, which is executing, but runs for hours. Is there a quicker way?

I have tried the following script

```
MATCH (install:type {name:"INSTALL"}),
path=(install)<-[:TYPE]-(installevent)<-[:PREV*]-(e:event)
WITH e,path,count(e.eventcat='Calls to Care') as eventcount
WHERE e.churnflag1>'0'
AND eventcount >1
RETURN  eventcount,count(path)
ORDER BY count(path) desc
LIMIT 25;
```

I expect this to return number of paths that have 1,2,3...Calls to care

Comment: Note that each distinct path will end in a single :event node. Perhaps you're looking for all :event nodes connected in this way to a distinct `install`? And maybe are you after paths that end in an :event that has no successive :event (basically the end :event of the chain, so you could get all other :event nodes in that single longest chain to that last :event node)?

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure what you mean by connected to a distinct install? The way my graph is structured is I have a single install for each customer in the beginning of each journey hence the reason I am querying it this way. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I think so. It's important to understand how you want to do the grouping of :events. If it's by `path`, it won't get what you want, since you will have many paths per install. If you're grouping by distinct `install`, then I think that's closer to what you want: the number of calls to care per install/customer?

Comment: Also, the `churnFlag` comparison may be incorrect. Do you really want a string comparison? And do you really only want to test that flag on the *last* node of each path?

Comment: hi, i have a graph per customer, so they all have an install, that is okay. I am querying for variable path length [:PREV*] hence e.churnflag will apply to all nodes in a journey. This query is running, but the issue is it is taking too much time and I was looking for a way to optimise it